# How to make a CSS menu to remain visible after a child has been clicked on

Tags: html, css, menubar, submenu

I have this CSS:

```
#menuBar {
  /*width: 960px;*/
  height: 35px;
  clear: both;
}

ul#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #0068b4;
}

ul#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#nav li a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background-color: #0068b4;
}

/* APPLIES THE ACTIVE STATE TO PARENT*/
ul#nav .currentParent a, ul#nav li:hover > a  {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #005899;
}

/* THE SUBMENU LIST HIDDEN BY DEFAULT */
ul#nav  ul {
  display: none;
}

/* WHEN THE FIRST LEVEL MENU ITEM IS HOVERED, THE CHILD MENU APPEARS */
ul#nav li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 97%;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 35px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

/* APPLIES THE ACTIVE STATE TO CHILD*/
ul#nav li ul li.currentChild a, ul#nav li:hover > ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #afafaf;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<div id="menuBar">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="javascript: void;">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="menu1submenuitem1.html">Menu 1 Submenu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu1submenuitem2.html">Menu 1 Submenu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu1submenuitem3.html">Menu 1 Submenu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript: void;">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="menu2submenuitem1.html">Menu 2 Submenu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu2submenuitem2.html">Menu 2 Submenu item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="currentParent"><a href="javascript: void;">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="menu3submenuitem1.html">Menu 3 Submenu item 1</a></li>
            <li class="currentChild"><a href="menu3submenuitem2.html">Menu 3 Submenu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu3submenuitem3.html">Menu 3 Submenu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using this to display a two level horizontal menu. What I want to achieve is that when an option from the second level is clicked I want the parent and the children itself to remain highlighted. To do this I'm actually building the HTML for the menu in the code behind of my ASP.net page and using the styles: currentParent and currentChild to highlight them. That's working, what I've not been able to figure out is how to make the second level that contains the child that was clicked to stay visible. I've tried by adding `display: none` in a lot of places, but nothing is working. I'm wondering if somebody can help me with this and give some advise of the modifications I need to add to the CSS to achieve this?

**EDIT 1:**

I've completed the code and reviewed that it's working (you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cesarvinas/ZQWe7/). You can see in the HTML code that I've applied the class *current Parent* to parent menu *Menu 3* and the class *currentChild* to submenu item *Menu 3 Submenu item 2*. With this, the parent and child are now highlighted. What I want in addition is that the row that contains the submenu items (the gray one): *Menu 3 Submenu item 1*, *Menu 3 Submenu item 2*, and *Menu 3 Submenu item 3* remains visible.

As I explained in the main post, I have added code to the code behind of the ASP .net page to build the HTML up and assign the CSS classes when necessary.

Is there a way to have a CSS class that I can assign to the parent `<li>` (in the example, the *Menu 3* parent) to keep its children visible?

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to the help I've received here, specially from 3dgoo, this is almost done. I've updated the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cesarvinas/ZQWe7/5/. However, to make the submenu items that are not current to remain silver (and not blue as in 3dgoo example) I've had to create one more CSS class ".notselected" that I'm applying to those submenu items that are not selected. My question is: is there a way to achieve the same without having to add an extra CSS class? This is what I've done:

```
ul#nav li ul li.notselected a,
ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<li class="currentParent"><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="notselected"><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 1</a></li>
        <li class="currentChild"><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 2</a></li>
        <li class="notselected"><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I've tried with this in the CSS:

```
ul#nav li ul li a,
ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

and removing the `class="notselected"` from the HTML, but it doesn't work. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Your current code is not working, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kSWAd/1/. Please update/fix it and explain more clearly what you want it to do.

Comment: Sorry, Shomz. I've fixed the code in the post and also created this: http://jsfiddle.net/cesarvinas/ZQWe7/ so you can review. I've also added more explanation in **EDIT 1**, please let me know if it's clearer now. I hope you can help.

Comment: No problem, just trying to help. It's much clearer now and I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the following css selector `ul#nav li.currentParent > ul` like so:

**CSS**

```css
...
ul#nav li.currentParent > ul, // Add this
ul#nav li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 97%;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 35px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul { // And add these three lines
    z-index: 10;
}
...
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQWe7/4/)**

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, 3dgoo. I've been able to make the additional changes so the other submenu items in the selected parent display as silver and not blue. However, I have one more question as I've had to create one more class ".notselected" that I'm adding to the not selected submenu items in order to keep them silver. Can you please check my second edit and tell me if there is another way of achieving the same without creating the extra class?

Comment: @CesarVinas - Here you are. I will write up an explanation later: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQWe7/21/

Comment: Thanks again, 3dgoo. I've seen more than one change in the CSS so, yes, I'd love the explanation. Whenever you can! :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the clicked item from the second row to be highlighted and the appropriate second row visible after clicking it.

If the menu will use standard links (page refreshing on each click) perhaps it would be the best to use an ASP variable to denote the current page and according to that variable make CSS modifications to make the correct submenu visible and the correct item highlighted (you can start from 3dgoo's CSS example selector `ul#nav li.currentParent > ul`).

The second case is that you're not refreshing the page on clicks (either using AJAX to load only parts of the page, for example). In that case, you'd have to use Javascript/jQuery to listen for clicks and change classes accordingly. This means that when you click an item, its parent `li` element needs to become the only `currentChild` class and its parent `currentParent`, of course.

EDIT

You can select all the `currentParent` submenu anchors like this: `ul#nav li.currentParent ul li a` and then add hover/active effects on `currentChild` after that.

Comment: Thanks, Shomz. My case is the first one and yes, I'm already using variables to identify the current page. There are no issues on that front. My problem is actualy the CSS and the modifications I have to do to the styles to accomplish the changes in the presentation of the menu bar. I'm reviewing 3dgoo's suggestions and so far it's working except that the submenu items from the visible row are now blue rather than silver so you are very welcome in case you have additional suggestions.

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQWe7/13/ ?
I replaced your `notselected` selector part of CSS with `ul#nav li.currentParent ul li a`